# What's wrong with populating a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to populate a dictionary `newDict` in following code:

```
def sessions():
    newDict = {}
    output = exe(['loginctl','list-sessions']) # uses subprocess.check_output(). returns shell command's multiline output
    i = 0;
    for line in output.split('\n'):
        words = line.split()
        newDict[i] = {'session':words[0], 'uid':words[1], 'user':words[2], 'seat':words[4]}
        i += 1
    stdout(newDict) # prints using pprint.pprint(newDict)
```

But it only keeps giving me error:

```
newDict[i] = {'session':words[0], 'uid':words[1], 'user':words[2], 'seat':words[4]}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I do `print words` in the loop, here's what I get:

```
['c3', '1002', 'john', 'seat0']
['c4', '1003', 'jeff', 'seat0']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is exe? Did you mean exec?

Comment: There's probably a line with less than 5 words, so `words[4]` raises an IndexError. You probably have an empty line at the end there, try `for line in output.strip().split('\n')` to get rid of it.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. Edited question.

Comment: @Rawing Did but didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it is a typo:
You use `words[4]` instead of `words[3]`.

BTW:
Here is a slightly improved version of your code. It uses `splitlines()` instead of `split('\n')` and skips empty lines. And it uses `enumerate()`, wich is a pretty neat function when it comes to counting entries while iterating over collections.

```
def sessions():
    newDict = {}
    output = exe(['loginctl','list-sessions']) #returns shell command's multiline output
    for i, line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
        if len(line.strip()) == 0:
            continue
        words = line.split()
        print words
        newDict[i] = {'session':words[0], 'uid':words[1], 'user':words[2], 'seat':words[3]}
    stdout(newDict) # prints using pprint.pprint(newDict)
```

Comment: yup, a typo. It works now :|. Thanks for pointing that out and improved code.

Comment: Oh. But please remove the 'print words' line. That is a debugging leftover. And worse: It's python2x style! ;-)

Comment: `if len(line.strip()) == 0:`
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: Sure you wrote `for i, line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):` instead of `for  line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):` ?

Answer (score 1):

Imo You should check if "words" isn't too short. It's most likely problem with list length after spliting some line (It has no enough elements) .

Comment: haha, because you are using words[4], it's 0,1,2,X,4 (bad index, your list is from 0 to 3!!!) Just simple mistake,

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that words, does not allways hold five items,

please try to print len(words) before assigning the dict.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with the dictionary itself, but with parsing the output. Here is an example of the output I obtain:

```
   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT            
        c2       1000 willem           seat0           

1 sessions listed.
```

Or the string version:

```
'   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT            \n        c2       1000 willem           seat0           \n\n1 sessions listed.\n'
```

This all appears on the `stdout`. The problem is -- as you can see - is that not every line contains four words (there is the empty line at the bottom). Or more pythonic:

```
>>> lines[2].split()
[]
```

You thus have to implement a check whether the line has four columns:

```
def sessions():
    newDict = {}
    output = exe(['loginctl','list-sessions']) # uses subprocess.check_output(). returns shell command's multiline output
    i = 0;
    for line in output.split('\n'):
        words = line.split()
        if len(words) >= 4:
            newDict[i] = {'session':words[0], 'uid':words[1], 'user':words[2], 'seat':words[3]}
            i += 1
    stdout(newDict)
```

(changes highlighted in boldface)

In the code I've also rewritten `words[4]` to `words[3]`.